# Overwrite function only for a particular instance in LUA

Tags: function, object, lua, overriding, overwrite

I basically don't look for an answer on how to do something but I found how to do it, yet want more information. Hope this kind of question is OK here. 
Since I just discovered this the code of a game I'm modding I don't have any idea what should I google for.

In Lua, I can have for example:

```
Account = {balance = 0}
function Account.withdraw (v)
     self.balance = self.balance - v
end
```

I can have (in another lua file)

```
function Account.withdrawBetter (v)
    if self.balance > v then 
      self.balance = self.balance - v
    end
end
```

....
--somewhere in some function, with an Account instance:
a1.withdraw = a1.withdrawBetter
`

What's the name for this "technique" so I can find some more information about it (possible pitfalls, performance considerations vs. override/overwrite, etc)? note I'm only changing `withdraw` for the particular instance (a1), not for every Account instance.

Bonus question: Any other oo programming languages with such facility?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### OO in Lua

First of all, it should be pointed out that Lua does not implement Object Oriented Programming; it has no concept of objects, classes, inheritance, etc.

If you want OOP in Lua, you have to implement it yourself. Usually this is done by creating a table that acts as a "class", storing the "instance methods", which are really just functions that accept the instance as its first argument.

Inheritance is then achieved by having the "constructor" (also just a function) create a new table and set its metatable to one with an `__index` field pointing to the class table. When indexing the "instance" with a key it doesn't have, it will then search for that key in the class instead.

In other words, an "instance" table may have no functions at all, but indexing it with, for example, `"withdraw"` will just try indexing the class instead.

Now, if we take a single "instance" table and add a `withdraw` field to it, Lua will see that it has that field and not bother looking it up in the class. You could say that this value *shadows* the one in the class table.

### *What's the name for this "technique"*

It doesn't really have one, but you should definitely look into metatables.

In languages that *do* support this sort of thing, like in Ruby (see below) this is often done with singleton classes, meaning that they only have a single instance.

### *Performance considerations*

Indexing tables, including metatables takes some time. If Lua finds a method in the instance table, then that's a single table lookup; if it doesn't, it then needs to first get the metatable and index that instead, and if that doesn't have it either and has its own metatable, the chain goes on like that.

So, in other words, this is actually *faster*. It does use up some more space, but not really that much (*technically* it could be quite a lot, but you really shouldn't worry about that. Nonetheless, [here's where you can read up on that](https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf), if you want to).

### *Any other oo programming languages with such facility?*

Yes, lots of 'em. Ruby is a good example, where you can do something like

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3]
array2 = [4, 5, 6]

def array1.foo
  puts 'bar'
end

array1.foo # prints 'bar'
array2.foo # raises `NoMethodError`
```

Comment: I'm aware of the considerations regarding OO in Lua you posted but thanks for that too. When you say that it doesn't have a name, you mean no name in Lua or not even in Rubi, I feel that overriding would not be proper even if foo is a method? My actual OO experience is Java.

Comment: @LucianHada Overriding is a good description, and what I'd google it as, but it's not as much its *name*. As I said, *singleton classes* is a related concept in "real" OOP, but Lua uses a prototype-like approach where the line between classes and objects is really just in the head of the programmer. In a way, each object is a *subclass* of its own, so this broadly falls under "subtyping", though that's a very inconvenient way to think about it.

Comment: At this point I fail to see the link between singletons and this, but maybe my fault and will look more into it. There could be a1, a2, etc instances of Account (yes, the game I'm modding has is implementation of OOP on Lua as you say) that are created by the engine, then I just come in the picture with my mod, have access to one or more such instance and "override" in this manner one of the methods (without affecting other instances)

Comment: My dilemma (performance, pitfalls, etc) is actually if to use this technique on an "object" when a condition becomes true then revert to the original function/method when the condition becomes false vs. more classical approach of overriding the "class method" and check the condition inside my implementation (calling the original function if condition=false)

Comment: Get the original method, make a new function with your condition and store it (so it's only closed once), then add it to the instances you want to override and leave them like that. That should be the most reliable way to do it.